# Trying to get two countdown timers on one web page and not working

Tags: html, css, timer

I'm currently using [this website's](http://www.rmkwebdesign.com/Countdown_Timers/help/index.php?article=14) code and it stopped working once one of the timers was finished.  When one timer was finished, the second timer stopped showing up.  Now, the second timer doesn't show up at all.

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPvOYj

CSS because I need code for whatever reason:

```
    body {
      font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    header {
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul,
    ol,
    dl {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    p {
      margin-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    h4 {
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    h5 {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .container {
      width: 1200px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .sidebar1 {
      margin-top: 150px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #EADCAE;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      float: left;
      z-index: 100;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
      border-left: 1px solid #666;
    }

    .content {
      margin-top: 150px;
      margin-left: 200px;
      padding-right: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      width: 999px;
      float: left;
      background: #FFF;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
      border-left: 1px solid #666;
      border-right: 1px solid #666;
      position: fixed;
      overflow-y: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    aside {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #EADCAE;
      padding: 10px 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content ul,
    .content ol {
      padding: 0 10px 10px 40px;
    }

    .fltrt {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 8px;
    }

    .fltlft {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 8px;
    }

    .clearfloat {
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
      font-size: 1px;
      line-height: 0px;
    }

    header,
    section,
    footer,
    aside,
    article,
    figure {}

    ul,
    ol,
    dl {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #0B09CB;
    }

    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navbar {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul il .subnav {
      display: block;
      display: none;
    }

    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
    }

    nav li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    }

    nav a,
    nav a:visited {
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
      display: block;
      width: 180px;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #C6D580;
    }

    nav a:hover,
    nav a:active,
    nav a:focus {
      background-color: #ADB96E;
      color: #FFF;
    }

    nav ul li {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul li > ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      left: 100%;
      top: -1px;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
    }

    table {
      width: 96%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th {
      background-color: #D6DCED;
    }

    a.back-to-top {
      display: none;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 40px;
      right: 40px;
      background: gold url("images/up-arrow.png") no-repeat center 43%;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      border-radius: 30px;
    }

    a:hover.back-to-top {
      background-color: #000;
    }

    #table1, #table2 {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: year2 is not defined`

Comment: Fixed that part (I had originally taken it out then just copied the one above it).  Updated codepen, and it still doesn't work on my side.  Do you see anything else?